# How to scale newtxmath fonts to match scaled garamondx

Tags: fonts, scaling, newtxmath, garamondx

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.5]{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx]{newtxmath}
% \usepackage[garamondx,scaled=0.5]{newtxmath} % <- doesn't work
% \usepackage[scaled=0.5]{newtxmath}           % <- works, but looks wrong
\begin{document}
\textsl{aaa} $aaa$
\end{document}
```

The math characters are obviously too big.  However, if I'm using the `garamondx` option for the `newtxmath` package, the `scaled` option doesn't work anymore.  How can I fix this and make the math characters smaller?

(I'm using 0.5 to make things more obvious.  In reality, I'm using 0.95.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I measure the height of an italic “a” with the scaling factor of 0.95, I get
a height of 4.24648pt. For a math italic “a” I get 4.51999pt.

Thus the scaling factor, to four decimal digits, should be 0.93949.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,scaled=0.93949]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{a}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$a$}\the\ht0

\textsl{aaa} $aaa$
\end{document}
```

**Important note** In order for the code to work, you need to update `garamondx` with `getnonfreefonts --sys` (or equivalent method); the new version was released on 2020-10-04.

[image]

---

#### Old answer for whom has not updated yet

If I measure the height of an italic “a” with the scaling factor of 0.95, I get
a height of 4.24648pt. For a math italic “a” I get 4.51999pt.

Thus the scaling factor, to four decimal digits, should be 0.93949.
Unfortunately

```
\usepackage[garamondx,scale=0.93949]{newtxmath}
```

bombs out because of an error in `omlzgmmi.fd` that has

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ntxmath@scaled\endcsname\relax
  \let\ntxmath@@scaled\@empty%
\else
  \edef\ntxmath@@scaled{s*[\csname ntxmath@scaled\endcsname]}%
\fi
```

but the code should rather be

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ntxmath@scaled\endcsname\relax
  \let\ntxmath@@scaled\@empty
\else
  \let\ntxmath@@scaled\ntxmath@scaled
\fi
```

because in the most recent releases of `newtxmath`, the macro `\ntxmath@scaled` already expands to `s*[<scaling factor>]`. (I guess that it used to expand to just the scaling factor).

Workaround: load yourself `zgmmi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,scaled=0.9395]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{zgmmi}{\skewchar \font =127}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{m}{it}{<-> \ntxmath@scaled zgmmi}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{b}{it}{<-> \ntxmath@scaled zgmbmi}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * zgmmi/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * zgmmi/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * zgmmi/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{zgmmi}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * zgmmi/b/sl}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sbox0{a}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$a$}\the\ht0

\textit{aaa} $aaa$
\end{document}
```

The first two lines show that the difference in height is negligible.

Comment: Wow!  I don't understand the details, but it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Frunobulax I just copied the relevant part of `omlzgmmi.fd` into the document, fixing the issue, that is using `\ntxmath@scaled` instead of the faulty `\ntxmath@@scaled`.

Comment: @Frunobulax I've contacted the maintainer who has promised a fix as soon as possible.

Comment: @Frunobulax The update can be downloaded with `getnonfreefonts` as usual. `:-)` Thanks to Michael Sharpe for his precious contributions.